# React Native - How to set numberOfLines for nested Text elements?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Having two  components, I would like to achieve a result similar to that used in e.g. Facebook Messenger - display the content of the message concatenated with the date of sending this message, but if the message is longer than two lines, then truncate its content in order to fit the date:

For example I have tried:

```
<Text numberOfLines={2}>
  <Text>{lastConversationMessageText}</Text>
  <Text>{lastConversationMessageDate}</Text>
</Text>
```

but it did not have the desired effect.

```
When lastConversationMessageText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit"
|Lorem ipsum dolor sit|
|amet - 10:30 AM      |
```

```
When lastConversationMessageText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
|Lorem ipsum dolor sit|
|amet, c... - 10:30 AM|
```